# EF6 - One to Zero-or-One relation - Own primary Key and CascadeDelete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, relational-database

I am trying to model a one to zero or one relation in EF6.

My model has an entity `Transmitter` and `MeasuringCell`.

A transmitter MUST have a measuring cell, but a cell can belong to one or zero transmitters.

When registering a Transmitter to DB, the transmitter must have a cell, but when registering a cell, it can be, that the target transmitter is not known at the time. In this case, after a time the cell is mounted in a new transmitter, then it's possible to make the relation.

So I want that both entities:

- Have their own PK (`Id`)
- Have FK to each other(`TransmitterId` in `MeasureCell`-Table / `MeasureCellId` in `Transmitter`-Table).
- A cell can't be related to 2 transmitters.
- When a transmitter is deleted, its cell should be deleted too.

But after lot of search and read, I am still not able to make it work.

Without a FK from MeasureCell to Transmitter (`TransmitterId`) all works great, but it would be nice to have it, for the case I need to know which transmitter a cell belongs to.

On the other side, without a FK `TransmitterId` I am still able to know which transmitter a cell belongs to, since `Transmitter` has FK `MeasureCellId` but the query would be more complicated/less performant.

Here a picture of (a part) of my model: 
[image]

and here my Fluent-APi Config for this relation:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MeasureCell>().HasOptional(x=>x.Transmitter)
           .WithRequired(x=>x.MeasureCell)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But how you can see the relationship is wrong and only PK's are used not FK. 
I've read a lot and seems to me that this is not supported by EF 6, but I'm still not sure.

Maybe I am modeling my entities in the wrong way?

The only way I get near to what I want is by creating to 1-to-Many relationships between them. 
[image]

[image]

But this way I'll have some headache, since I will need to manually assure a cell is not referenced by two transmitters and I need to be "careful" when saving to DB and the code will loke like:

```
var transmitter = context.Transmitters.Add(transmitter);
context.SaveChanges();
transmitter.MeasureCell.transmitter = transmitter;
context.SaveChanges();
```

And this looks REALLY weird to me...so I suppose I should not be doing that...

### Update

I already implemented this relation corectly and understand how EF handles it, by deleting `TransmitterId` in `MeasureCell` and configuring the relation like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Transmitter>()
      .HasRequired(x => x.MeasureCell)
      .WithOptional(x => x.Transmitter)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But I still have an issue, or still do something wrong. Since this way, the `Transmitter` is the dependant entity and the cascade deletion happens only when deleting a `MeasureCell`.

With any other configuration, I was not able to put the FK in `MeasureCell`-Table , to make `Transmitter` the parent in the relation, since the relation didn't work as expected( i.e. EF has created other columns, or not set the FK to the proper column) or I got some error when creating the `context`(i.e EF expected for ex. a '*' multiplicator at the side of `MeasureCell` - 1-to-Many-relation)

Since in my case a Transmitter has to have a `MeasureCell`, but a `MeasureCell` must not have a `Transmitter`, it always put the FK in `Transmitter`-Table, making it the dependant. This way, when I delete a `Transmitter`, it's `MeasureCell` is not being deleted. Instead, the cascade delete happens when deleting a `MeasureCell`, the related `Transmitter` is deleted too.

**Problem I'm trying to model**

In the "real world" in my company, we build first a `MeasureCell`, which will be registered to the DB and then waits until it's built in a `Transmitter`. After a time a transmitter is sold, and we built it. At this time, the `Transmitter` is registered and gets a `MeasureCell` assigned.

So, a `Transmitter` needs only a `MeasureCell` to be registered, but a `MeasureCell`  can be registered **without** a `Transmitter`, since like I said, at the time of the `MeasureCell` registration is not known, which `Transmitter` will it be assigned to.

But maybe I am **still working wrong with EF** or **approaching the problem wrong** or maybe I just **met a limitation of EF6**??

Comment: Having circular relationship (2 tables referencing each other with FKs) is very poor relational database design which only causes problems rather than solving anything, thus should be avoided when posssible. What about EF6, it supports one-to-one via FK, but not naturally and with limitations. If you are not constrained with an existing database, the best model is the EF6 default (and best supported) [Shared Primary Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev. Will take a look. I already suspected that's not good design.

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated my question. I got it some kind of working, but not like I think it should....would be great, if you could take a quick look :)

Comment: I think the latest design is ok and is the maximum you can get from relational database (thus EF). The "real word" scenario is a business logic / workflow which cannot be handled automatically by relational database. It has to be implemented via application logic, i.e. after deleting a `Transmitter`, also delete the associated `MeasureCell`. Of if you prefer, instead of deleting a `Transmitter`, delete the `MeasureCell` (they have the same PK) and let the cascade delete do the rest.